# Marshalling in c# ( Passing structure to an unmanaged type )

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I have a c++ dll which exposes the following function

```
long func(struct name * myname)
{
     strcpy(myname->firstname,"rakesh");
     strcpy(myname->lastname,"agarwal");
     return S_OK;
}

struct name
{
    char firstname[100];
    char lastname[100];
}
```

I want to call this function from a C# application , so I do the following :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
unsafe public struct name
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=100)]
    public string firstname;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 100)]
    public string lastname;
} ;


[DllImport("C++Dll.dll")]
public unsafe static extern long func(name[] myname);

name[] myname = new name[1];
func(myname);
```

The application builds successfully. When the C# application .exe is run, the function `func()` is called successfully and it is able to populate the fields successfully inside the dll. But when the function returns to the C# application, the variable `myname` still conatins null values for the struct fields(`firstname` and `lastname`).

Please suggest changes so that I am able to populate the fields values of `myname` (so that after the function `func()` finishes execution, the variable `myname->firstname` contains "rakesh" and `myname->lastname` contains "agarwal".

Note: StringBuilder cannot be used inside the structure.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using an array, pass the struct by reference.  For a PInvoke call, a ref struct will be translated into a pointer to the struct.  The ref argument also tells the CLR to marshal data in both directions, to native code and then back out again.

```
[DllImport("C++Dll.dll")]
public unsafe static extern long func(ref name myname);
```

Also, if you're doing a lot of interop work I suggest you check out the PInvoke interop assistant ([link](http://codeplex.com/clrinterop)).  This tool will automatically convert the majority of C type definitions (including structs, enums, unions and function pointers) into their corresponding C# or VB.Net types.  It will additionally convert signatures which contain these types.

Answer (score 3):

Declare the import as `public unsafe static extern long func(ref name myname)`, and call it as:

```
name myname = new name();
func(ref myname);
```

You probably don't need the unsafe declarations on the name structure or import declaration, by the way.